# Adding a new Web Front End Server to existing SharePoint 2010 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We have a SharePoint 2010 server farm with 2 Application Servers, 2 Web Front End Servers and database server.
We want to add one more Web Front End Server to the farm. After adding a server to the farm, how can it contains the IIS Sites that are already available in the other 2 Web Front End Servers.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 7):

When you run the products and technologies wizard on the new WFE and join it to the farm, all IIS sites will automatically be provisioned on the server, and all features deployed through SharePoint will be deployed on the new WFE. That server will match any existing server in the farm from a base configuration standpoint, excluding anything you've done manually on each of the other servers (but you shouldn't be manually deploying things anyway).

The base services will be started, and if you want any additional services to run you will need to go into "Manage Services on Server" and start them.

It should go without saying, but I will say it. Make sure you're running the products and technologies app as the installation account, and that account is a local admin; otherwise things will likely not provision correctly.

If you've got web applications provisioned as HTTPS, you'll need to take the appropriate measures to get the SSL cert configured on the servers; that is something SharePoint won't do for you.

Once you've done this, simply add that server into your load balancing array and you're good to go.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate through

Central Admin --> System Settings --> Manage Services on server

Make sure "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" service is started on your new front end, and SharePoint will work it's magic.

I would suggest keeping SharePoint Server Search started too

Answer (score 2):

When you add a new Web Front End to the existing SharePoint Server farm, SharePoint automatically creates IIS sites on the new server.

Answer (score -1):

As Ashish said SharePoint automatically create IIS sites.But after adding new WFE to the farm, you have to deploy all the custom settings you have deployed on old WFE to new WFE server also.

Comment: What "Custom Settings" are you referring to? SharePoint will handle all feature deployments automatically. The only "custom" setting you should have to do manually would be SSL certs or NLB, as applicable.