# Scaling single sharepoint server to 2 tier

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We currently have a single server for sharepoint 2010. Now we are planning to scale it to 2 tier as 1 server will act as web front, holding only web tier
and 2 nd server will hold database & application server.

I know about xslt and dwvp webparts will work, but what about custom webpart?
How should i move them so they work as it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate to [Adding a new Web Front End Server to existing SharePoint 2010 Farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20749/adding-a-new-web-front-end-server-to-existing-sharepoint-2010-farm)

Did you install Sharepoint as a Standalone or Scalable Farm option?
If you chose Standalone, then you're pretty much out of luck.
If you chose the Farm option, then all you need to do is:
On your new server, install the Sharepoint binaries (run setup) and make sure you get your patches/updates to the same level as your original level.

Next up, run through the Sharepoint Technologies Wizard and click add server to farm.

You dont have to worry about your custom webparts and custom code. Sharepoint takes care of deploying those to your new server once it's provisioned.

Comment: yes we installed it as a standalone.Our network admin has moved everything and rest works fine. just custom webparts got broken. so you mean there is no any direct way to get custom webparts as they were. right?

Comment: If you followed the right process of adding a server to the farm, then there is no need to migrate the webparts. Web parts are part of solutions and solution files (such as features and assemblies) gets migrated automatically. If you however manually went and deployed/updated files in the 12/14 hive, then these won't be migrated. Tell us what the exceptions or errors you are getting with your web parts